# How to determine the following coefficient?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I have such $$[x^8](1-5x^4)^{-2}(1+3x)^{-6}$$
I simplify as $$[x^8]\sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{n+2-1}{2-1}(5x^4)^n \cdot \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{n+6-1}{6-1}(-3x)^n $$

$$[x^8]\sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{n+1}{1}5^n(x^{4n}) \cdot \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{n+5}{5}(-3^n)x^n $$

I don't know what to do with the multiplication in there and the further steps

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see cauchy product of series

Comment: For clarity, use different letters, say $n$ and $m$, for the index variables on the two sums.  What ways are there to have $4n+m = 8$?

Comment: The 1st sum has $x^0,x^4,x^8$ and terms with higher powers which you can ignore. The 2nd sum has $x^0,x^1,x^2,\dots,x^8$ and higher powers you don't need. Now, multiply!

Comment: Making any progress, xni?

Comment: Yes, I get it, thanks for your help.

Comment: Good, xni. Let me encourage you to write it up, and to post an answer.